# Immutable JS - converting a collection of Maps to a List

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have the following structure in the project im working on (uses immutable JS):

> ```
> data :[{name: 'john', surname: 'smith', children: [{name: 'sam'}, {name: 'ben'}]},
>        {name: 'jane', surname: 'jones', children: [{name: 'tim'}, {name: 'amy'}]}]
> ```

the object is converted to immutable JS via fromJS().

I need a new object in the following structure:

> ```
> data :[{name: 'john', surname: 'smith', children: ['sam','ben']},
>        {name: 'jane', surname: 'jones', children: ['tim','amy']}]
> ```

Any pointers much appreciated.

Comment: What's the point of updating an immutable collection? Don't you should create a new list instead?

Comment: i should rephrase it as creating a a new resulting object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pure JS answer of Christian doesn't exactly apply to immutable.js objects, so here are a few ways to do it with immutable.js's collection API.

There are more options (e.g. `reduce`), feel free to check [the docs](https://immutable-js.com/docs/latest@main/); the method descriptions usually come with examples.

```js
const raw = [{name: 'john', surname: 'smith', children: [{name: 'sam'}, {name: 'ben'}]},
       {name: 'jane', surname: 'jones', children: [{name: 'tim'}, {name: 'amy'}]}];

const data = Immutable.fromJS(raw);

function run(name, operation) {
  let result;
  console.time(name);
  for(let i=0; i < 50000; i++){
    result = operation();
  }
  console.timeEnd(name);
  console.log(result1.toJS());
}


run('simple', () => {
  // simply updating objects inside a mapping
  result1 = data.map(
    person => person.update('children',
      kidObjs => kidObjs.map(
        kid => kid.get('name')
      )
    )
  );
});


run('withMutations and setIn', () => {
  // using withMutations and setIn
  result2 = data.withMutations(list => {
    list.forEach((val, idx) => {
      list.setIn(
        [idx, 'children'],
        val.get('children').map(kid => kid.get('name'))
      )
    });
  });
});

run('withMutations and update', () => {
  // slightly faster by using withMutations set/update
  result2 = data.withMutations(list => {
    list.forEach((val, idx) => {
      list.set(idx, val.update('children', kids => kids.map(kid => kid.get('name'))))
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/4.0.0-rc.14/immutable.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like that should works

> data.map(d => {d.name, d.surname, children: d.children.map(child => child.name)});

Comment: shouldn't d.name etc be d.get('name') as they are immutable JS objects.

Comment: You are probably right, I didn't pay attention to the library

Answer (score 1):

I would go with map and reduce:

```js
const data = [{name: 'john', surname: 'smith', children: [{name: 'sam'}, {name: 'ben'}]},
       {name: 'jane', surname: 'jones', children: [{name: 'tim'}, {name: 'amy'}]}];
       
var result = data.map(person => {
  return { name: person.name, 
           surname: person.surname, 
           children: person.children.reduce((acc, c) => {acc.push(c.name); return acc;}, []) }});
 
  console.log(result)
```

Comment: shouldn't d.name etc be d.get('name') as they are immutable JS objects? I have posted the resulting structure after i converted to JS objects (via .toJS())

Comment: I don't know the exact syntax of ImmutableJS but it shouldn't be difficult to convert above answer to it.